# Write an application that can support .Net Core and .Net framework

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have been working on java and my new project is on .Net .
Now we have to create a new project/solution that supports older versions of .Net framework if its on premises and at the same time support .Net Core when working on Cloud. For example if i have a encryption functionality , both Core and .Net are written separately but should access the respective info based on if its on premises or on cloud.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/porting/project-structure

This link gives an outline but its very vague. 
How to organize the project structure , can anyone share some sample code/examples that support both .net core and .net.

Comment: You could take a look at flubu it targets .net 4.6 and ..netcoreapp 1.0 https://bitbucket.org/zoroz/flubu.core/wiki/Home

Comment: .NET Core also works on premise.

Answer (score 1):

There's an example solution that illustrates how to support multiple frameworks linked to from that article you mentioned [here](http://%20%20%3CPropertyGroup%3E%20%20%20%20%20%3CTargetFrameworks%3Enet452;net461;netstandard1.6%3C/TargetFrameworks%3E%20%20%20%3C/PropertyGroup%3E)

It does depend on which versions of VS and .NET you're targeting, but assuming you're on 2017 essentially you add another target framework to your csproj file like this:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>net452;net461;netstandard1.6</TargetFrameworks>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Personally I'd avoid doing this if I could, you're likely to get different behaviour in the cloud to locally which is never a good plan.